# How to create a dynamic query from the dictionary by checking the length

Tags: python, dictionary

dictionary is below. Below is sample dictionary of length 2 and 3. By checking the condition need to generate the query dynamically

a = `[{'data': 'abc'}, {'prod': 'def'}]`

- if len(a) = 2:
  #below query has to generate

```
     "query": {
       "bool": {
         "should": [
           {
             "query_string": {
               "query": "*abc*",
               "fields": [
                 "data"
               ]
             }
           },
           {
             "query_string": {
               "query": "*def*",
               "fields": [
                 "prod"
               ]
             }
           }
         ]
       }
     }
   }
```

a = `[{'data': 'abc'}, {'prod': 'def'},{'email': '@gmail'}]`

- if len(a) = 3
  #below is the query

  ````
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "*abc*",
              "fields": [
                "data"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "*def*",
              "fields": [
                "prod"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "*@gmail.com*",
              "fields": [
                "email"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }```
  ````

Basically if dictionary keep on adding `{"query_string": {"query": "*@gmail.com*","fields": ["email"]}}`  the query also keep on adding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
a = [{'data': 'abc'}, {'prod': 'def'}]
result = {"query": {
       "bool": {
         "should": []
         }
       }
}

for item in a:
    for k, v in item.items():
        result['query']['bool']['should'].append({
            "query_string": {
            "query": f"*{v}*",
            "fields": [
                 k
               ]}
             })
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'query': {'bool': {'should': [{'query_string': {'fields': ['data'],
                                                 'query': '*abc*'}},
                               {'query_string': {'fields': ['prod'],
                                                 'query': '*def*'}}]}}}
```

Comment: why we need to give {v}

Comment: That is required by `f` string...https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/